# git status does not see changes applied remotely (github)

Tags: git, github, git-remote, git-status

```
 git status
```

says: `"Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'"`
   the origin/master is being tracked well after:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=remotes/origin/master
```

Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

connection to the remote repo is OK. (proxy is set correctly)

```
 git pull
```

sees the difference and pulls the required. Why would "Git status" not see the difference?

Comment: Git doesn't perform any sort of automatic check of remote repositories. You would need to run `git remote update` (or `git fetch`) to make your local repository aware of the remote changes.

Comment: Except for `git fetch` and `git push`, pretty much *everything* Git does just works locally. (`git remote update` is another way to spell `git fetch`, mostly, and `git pull` actually runs `git fetch` first, so those are covered under `git fetch`. `git ls-remote` and a few other `git remote` commands will contact another Git, but those aren't things most people do most of the time.)

Comment: to summarise - the assumption that `--set-upstream-to` would equip `git status` with the ability to see the updates done on the remote repository is false.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-status%5D+branch+is+up+to+date